# Maintenance friendly list - image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure something out with HTML / CSS but I can't get in the right direction and was hoping you guys can give me a little push in the right direction.

What I am trying to do is recreate something similar to the 'Nieuws' section on the following webpage (https://www.iculture.nl/).

I can recreate the look and feel (see code below). But it doesn't allow for easy addition of new news. I tried fixing it with applying `<li>` but that didn't seem to work either. As the pictures kept overlapping.

```
.news-item-0 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 990px;
    margin-top: 280px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(77, 76, 76);
}

.news-item-0 img, .news-item-1 img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.news-title-0, .news-subtitle-0, .news-main-0, .news-title-1, .news-subtitle-1, .news-main-1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
}

.news-title-0, .news-title-1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.news-subtitle-0, .news-subtitle-1 {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
}

.news-item-1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 990px;
    margin-top: 280px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(77, 76, 76);
}

.news-item-1 img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML, and ideally make a snippet, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is your starting point:

```css
.news-item-0 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 990px;
    margin-top: 280px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(77, 76, 76);
}

.news-item-0 img, .news-item-1 img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.news-title-0, .news-subtitle-0, .news-main-0, .news-title-1, .news-subtitle-1, .news-main-1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
}

.news-title-0, .news-title-1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.news-subtitle-0, .news-subtitle-1 {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
}

.news-item-1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 990px;
    margin-top: 280px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(77, 76, 76);
}

.news-item-1 img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-item-0">
  <img/>
  <div class="news-title-0">Title0</div>
  <div class="news-subtitle-0">Subtitle0</div>
  <div class="news-main-0">Content0</div>
</div>

<div class="news-item-1">
  <img/>
  <div class="news-title-1">Title1</div>
  <div class="news-subtitle-1">Subtitle1</div>
  <div class="news-main-1">Content1</div>
</div>
```

It's a bad idea to add the index into your class names, as you won't be able to reuse any of your CSS unless you keep copy-pasting your class names as you were doing. 
A better approach is to define one name and to keep using that name.

If you need a specific post to differ, you can use pseudo-classes like [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child#) in your CSS-selector.

Your second problem came from the use of `position: absolute` and `margin-top: 280px`.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

In short: your news posts were getting a fixed position on the page. Since they were all getting the same position, they were stacked ontop of eachother.

```css
.news-item {
  width: 990px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(77, 76, 76);
  min-height: 150px;
}

.news-item img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.news-title,
.news-subtitle,
.news-main {
  font-family: Calibri;
}

.news-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.news-subtitle {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
}
```

```html
<div class="news-item">
  <img/>
  <div class="news-title">Title0</div>
  <div class="news-subtitle">Subtitle0</div>
  <div class="news-main">Content0</div>
</div>

<div class="news-item">
  <img/>
  <div class="news-title">Title1</div>
  <div class="news-subtitle">Subtitle1</div>
  <div class="news-main">Content1</div>
</div>
```